# Collect the data returned by a group of post requests and post another single request

Tags: jquery, database, post, asynchronous, each

I have a hash in jQuery. Its called dict.

To populate that hash, I call the createDict() function which will return something like below,

{"12|345" => "http://www.one.com",
"67|890" => "http://www.two.com"}

```
var dict = createDict();
```

Now for each elements of the hash I execute "grabData" method which is nothing but a post request,

```
    $.each(dict, function( key, value ) { 

      data = key.split("|")[0];    

      var a = "";        

      //Calling the function that is a post request.
      grabData(data,"/url",function(returned) {   

          alert(returned); //=> Positive              

          a = returned;

      });

      alert(returned); // => negative

      alert(a); // => negative

    });
```

//Definition grabData

```
function grabData(input,url,callback){

    $.post(url,input,function(data){                    

          $("div#answer").html(data);

          callback(data); 
     });

}
```

**Questions:**

1. For each elements in the dict hash, Im executing a group post
   request and getting the returned value and updating the
   "div#answer".
2. I want to collect the returned value in another array or hash and
       run another single post request whose input will be this array or
       hash.

   **Note:**

> The second single post request will update the database, so I
>       dont want this to happen during the first group of post requests.

Comment: Your questions aren't actually questions. What have you tried so far and what problems are you having?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. You see the access to the variable "returned" is not available outside the grabData function. But I want to collect all the returned variables and do another post outside the $.each. How do I do it?

Comment: See answer below, hope that helps

Comment: I will try your solution and let you know. Please wait!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the total number of request you are going to fire(ie No of elements in `dict`). So that you can set a counter and keep on increasing for each request and on final request you can collect the data and make a single post request.

```
var total = dict.length;
```

Set a counter

```
var counter = 0;
var returnedData = [];
```

Then run your each loop

```
$.each(dict, function( key, value ) { 
//your loop settings

...
   //Calling the function that is a post request.
      grabData(data,"/url",function(returned) {   

          alert(returned); //=> Positive              

          a = returned;
      returnedData .push(returned);
      counter++;
      if(counter == total ){
        //Collect the returned value, which will be in `returnedData` array.
        //make post request with collected data
      }
 });
});
```

Comment: alert(dict.length); returns "undefined"..why?..dict = {}.

Comment: I used this to get the length of a hash, var total = 0;

   for (var i in dict){
    
    total++;
    
   } ,otherwise, it properly worked your approach. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put the code which runs the POST inside your call back function, and check whether you have all the data you need each time the callback function runs. Something like:

```
function grabData(input,url,callback){
    var allDataSoFar = [];
    $.post(url,input,function(data){                    
        $("div#answer").html(data);
        allDataSoFar.push(data);
        if (haveGotAllDataYet(allDataSoFar){
             $.post(...)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: More or less your approach is same as that of Ashwins but he was very clear about the "haveGotAllDataYet" you were talking about. He helped to use the length of the hash and figure out when to trigger the final post. But thanks for your contribution.